# Keyboard with dead keys layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My keyboard has a layout where some keys need to be pressed twice for them to work. For example, the character `

I ask this because I can't use the keyboard shortcut CTRL + `

The keyboard doesn't recognize the shortcut. I imagine it's because the ` key doesn't work the first time I press it. I know I can change the shortcut, but I don't want to, since I work on a computer that others use.

Is there a way to make these "dead keys" work when pressed the first time? My system is Windows 11 x64.

Comment: What layout? Do you mean this is on purpose or is the keyboard broken or not functioning properly? What does this keyboard shortcut do? Have you looked into creating your own keyboard combinations? This is a well documented process, so what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Keyboard is working fine, some keyboards have internal layouts to work with special characters that use accents and other symbols. Like I said before, I know I can change the shortcut, but I don't want to, because other people use the computer. That's why I was asking if it is possible to make the key combination work without having to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, without "changing anything" you cannot change anything.

In order to do this you will need to choose and use a utility for creating/modifying key combinations. These are plentiful and well documented.